# Why is accessing the X server locally from vim so slow?

Tags: linux, vim

I'm having problems with slow startup time in vim. I used the `--startuptime` flag to investigate, with the following output:

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.003  000.003: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.082  000.079: Allocated generic buffers
000.103  000.021: locale set
000.112  000.009: GUI prepared
000.115  000.003: clipboard setup
000.119  000.004: window checked
000.496  000.377: inits 1
000.513  000.017: parsing arguments
000.514  000.001: expanding arguments
000.527  000.013: shell init
1000.786  1000.259: xsmp init
1001.055  000.269: Termcap init
1001.108  000.053: inits 2
1001.315  000.207: init highlight
1001.702  000.298  000.298: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/debian.vim
1002.839  000.950  000.950: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
1002.954  001.139  000.189: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
1013.304  000.029  000.029: sourcing /home/daniel/.vim/ftdetect/tree.vim
1013.520  010.526  010.497: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
1013.594  011.841  000.176: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
1013.642  012.296  000.157: sourcing $VIM/vimrc
1014.184  000.410  000.410: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/debian.vim
1014.724  000.270  000.270: sourcing /home/daniel/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle.vim
1015.021  000.197  000.197: sourcing /home/daniel/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle/config.vim
1015.683  000.015  000.015: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
1015.782  000.040  000.040: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin.vim
1015.875  000.035  000.035: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent.vim
1016.281  000.298  000.298: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/nosyntax.vim
1016.592  000.211  000.211: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
1016.715  000.390  000.179: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
1016.744  000.796  000.108: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
1016.810  000.011  000.011: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
1016.875  000.009  000.009: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin.vim
1016.937  000.009  000.009: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent.vim
1017.797  000.567  000.567: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim
1017.906  000.013  000.013: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
1018.017  000.011  000.011: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin.vim
1018.085  000.010  000.010: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent.vim
1018.539  000.209  000.209: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
1019.006  000.203  000.203: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
1019.385  000.203  000.203: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
1020.619  002.482  001.867: sourcing /home/daniel/.vim/colors/minimalist.vim
1020.903  000.207  000.207: sourcing /home/daniel/.vim/autoload/camelcasemotion.vim
1021.384  007.678  002.596: sourcing ~/.vim/vimrc
1021.387  000.098: sourcing vimrc file(s)
1022.101  000.586  000.586: sourcing /home/daniel/.vim/plugin/camelcasemotion.vim
1022.503  000.221  000.221: sourcing /home/daniel/.vim/autoload/ctrlp/mrufiles.vim
1022.753  000.632  000.411: sourcing /home/daniel/.vim/plugin/ctrlp.vim
1023.103  000.273  000.273: sourcing /home/daniel/.vim/bundle/tabular/plugin/Tabular.vim
1023.450  000.090  000.090: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
1023.712  000.247  000.247: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
1023.994  000.268  000.268: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
1024.023  000.013  000.013: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
1024.263  000.229  000.229: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
1024.941  000.662  000.662: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
1025.013  000.043  000.043: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
1025.066  000.033  000.033: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
1025.286  000.202  000.202: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
1025.408  000.098  000.098: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
1025.658  000.231  000.231: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
1025.937  000.246  000.246: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
1026.087  000.026  000.026: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim80/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim
1026.105  000.839: loading plugins
1026.146  000.041: loading packages
1026.676  000.274  000.274: sourcing /home/daniel/.vim/bundle/tabular/autoload/tabular.vim
1028.950  002.703  002.429: sourcing /home/daniel/.vim/bundle/tabular/after/plugin/TabularMaps.vim
1028.955  000.106: loading after plugins
1029.433  000.478: inits 3
1029.736  000.303: reading viminfo
1031.466  001.730: setup clipboard
1031.483  000.017: setting raw mode
1031.490  000.007: start termcap
1031.510  000.020: clearing screen
1031.954  000.444: opening buffers
1032.050  000.096: BufEnter autocommands
1032.052  000.002: editing files in windows
1032.146  000.094: VimEnter autocommands
1032.148  000.002: before starting main loop
1033.609  001.461: first screen update
1033.613  000.004: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

The offending line is clearly `1000.786  1000.259: xsmp init`, which I believe indicates that vim is connecting to the X server.

Googling suggests that the only way to fix this is to recompile without `xclip`. But people use the system clipboard all the time, and most of the issues raised about this kind of slow connection seem to be related to using vim remotely, which I am not doing. The fact the delay is so close to exactly one second also makes me suspicious of something silly that might be easily fixed.

So, what can I do to investigate how slowly X is initialising here?

Extra info: I have this issue when running vim with bash through both gnome-terminal and the simple terminal.

Comment: Update: Restarting my computer appears to have fixed the problem, I don't know why.

Comment: I'm noticing the exact same issue. The slow startup times have only started yesterday, and the only 2 possible causes I can think of is 1. running my windows virtualbox VM (does vbox tinker with X11 server at all?) and 2. I recently ran `pacman -Syu` to update the system and haven't restarted since, so maybe something just needed a restart after updating?

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem after having had a window manager compositor crash my Xorg session (or at least my window manager), kicking me out of all my applications in the process.  In my new Xorg session I opened a new terminal and reconnected to my existing tmux (2.8) session, but noticed that I now had that delay in starting Vim, exactly one full second in "xsmp init", only when using Vim through tmux.  It's such a perfect second that I suspect it's a timeout, perhaps due to tmux trying to connect to my previous Xorg instance.

**What worked for me:** I exited my tmux session entirely, confirming that no tmux process was still running, then I launched a fresh tmux session.  Delay gone!

So I guess tmux has problems with an Xorg session disappearing from under it.

Comment: I don't remember, but it's very possible I was running tmux at the time of writing. Not sure about a crashed X session.

Comment: This describes an issue I was just facing to a T! I was going crazy worrying something had gone wrong with my vim set up. And what you suggest here worked perfectly - my Xorg session crashed, I logged back in, got back to my tmux, noticed the slowness, was confused, found your answer, killed tmux and relaunched it again and I'm back to my regular old vim startup time.

Comment: I just confirmed that it was my `tmux` session. After I killed all tmux sessions and re-launched it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem when running Vim (The regular vim from the `vim-gtk3` package) on Xmonad on Ubuntu.

Adding the following to my `.xprofile` solved it:

```
export SESSION_MANAGER=
```

Doing this preserves Vim's X-clipboard capabilities (copy/pasting using the `"` register) while getting rid of the 1 second delay at startup.

Where does this answer come from?
By looking at Vim's source code I indeed confirmed it tries to make some connection, timing out after 1s. Digging up the `xsmp` protocol I discovered that the specified environment variable for this is `SESSION_MANAGER`, and checking it I confirmed it was pointing to something that was likely dead in my case (the "other" window-manager in my distro)

I suspect the same will be true for sessions inside Tmux, when the surrounding environment is restarted.